# What is the right order of wxWidgets libs for MinGW Linker when building an application?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, mingw, wxwidgets

For some days now I dive into wxWidgets. I succeeded to compile the libs and build the minimal example and another example from a tutorial. All under Win 10 with MinGW GCC 12.2 and Eclipse CDT.
Now I created an XRC file and took a small program from a tutorial to use this XRC file but that produced a long list of undefined reference linker errors. Searching for a solution I found hints that it may have something to do with the order the libs are given in linker settings. Also I found the dependency diagram of the wxWidgets libs and started to resort the libs in linker settings.
I managed to strongly reduce the number of errors and finally succeded with linking without any error.
Now my questions:

- Why is the order important?
- Is there a right order, or is it dependent on my program eg the included header files?
- Where can I find the right order or how can I find it out? (This one time took me three hours!)
- How can I determine which libs are needed at all?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How can I find out the order of the libraries?

You can try to build xrc sample found in the samples\xrc directory the same way you build minimal one and look at the command generated.
2. Why is it important?

Because if function in library A calls a function from library B the linker need to know first what is library B. It can't guess where that function in library B is. So it throws an undefined reference to function XXX.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The order of libs using GNU GCC (mingw is a Windows version of it) matters a lot.

> Why is the order important?

See a good explanation in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/3871028)

> Is there a right order, or is it dependent on my program eg the
> included header files?

The right order depends on where a function is called and where it's implemented. Headers are not involved here.

> Where can I find the right order or how can I find it out?
>
>  How can I  determine which libs are needed at all?

In the wx minimal sample dir you may find `makefile.gcc`.

About the end, look for macros like `$(__WXLIB_CORE_p)` that shows you need `libwxmsw32ud_core.a` (exact name depends on your wx configuration). Add them all to your project. And perhaps some other special, like `libwxmsw32ud_aui.a`

Also look for `-luser32` (with low 'L') and so. They are Windows likely required libs. Again, add them all.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the order important?

This is just how the linker works, at least when using static linking. Another answer has already provided a link to an answer with more details.

> Is there a right order, or is it dependent on my program eg the included header files?

The order corresponds to the libraries dependencies and is not affected by the included headers.

> can I find the right order or how can I find it out?

In general, if you get an undefined symbol for a library you're already linking with, you need to move this library later in the list. Specifically for wxWidgets, the libraries dependencies are [documented here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/page_libs.html) and you need to specify them in this order, i.e. always link with the library `A` having a dependency on the library `B` in the order `-lA -lB`.

> How can I determine which libs are needed at all?

For wxWidgets, each class or function specifies which library it is defined in. E.g. If you look at [wxWebRequest documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_web_request.html) you can see "Library: wxNet" there, which means that you have to link with this library (and it needs to come before "base" in your linking list because of the above).